# When is Cordova based hybrid apps preferred over React Native development?

Tags: cordova, mobile, react-native

In mobile app development, React native has an edge over cordova based hybrid apps in terms of

1. Performance,
2. Native look and feel
3. Access to Native device features and much more

Is there any use-case where cordova based hybrid apps are preferred over react native app development?

Comment: I feel like this question might attract opinion-based answers, as this question might heavily depend on your (companies) background. Possible reasons might go from not having to learn a new framework to Cordova's maturity...

Comment: While react native is predominantly android/ios specific, Cordova helps you build for Windows too.

Comment: @sumanj fyi https://github.com/Microsoft/react-native-windows